# Red carded player

Tags: football, suspension

Can a player who received a red card during the game play the next game if the referee did not submit a report stating the player who received the red card during the game? Report shows no red cards issued.

Comment: What competition is this in? What do the disciplinary regulations say? Some have a clause that state being shown the red card serves as notice of at least a one week suspension. Others do not.

Comment: I'm voting to close, as in the absence of further information from the asker, this question is too broad.